# Android studio button taking me to wrong activity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm relatively new to Android Studio, this is my 2nd project. I'm currently having an issue that just recently appeared when when I run my app, when I click on the create_account button on the main menu activity. Its sending me to my ViewlogActivity for some reason. And when I click on my Viewlogs button it does nothing.  I double checked my intents and have both activities in my manifest file. Whats going on?

My Code:

```
Manifest File:                                                     
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                s<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<!--        <activity-->
<!--        android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"-->
<!--        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">-->
<!--        <intent-filter>-->
<!--            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->

<!--            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
<!--        </intent-filter>-->
<!--    </activity>-->

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateAccountActivity2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewLogActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LogoutActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>





**Main Activity Buttons:** 

Button create_account_button = findViewById(R.id.create_account);
        create_account_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call the create account activity
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick for create account called");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateAccountActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        Button login_button = findViewById(R.id.login);
        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call the login Activity
                Log.d("Login", "onClick for login activity called");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



        Button logout_button = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call the logout Activity
                Log.d("Logout", "onClick for logout activity called");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogoutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        Button view_logs_button = findViewById(R.id.viewlogs);
        create_account_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call the view log activity
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick for view log called");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewLogActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        Button exit_button = findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            // call to exit the application
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Exit", "onClick for exit called");
                finish();

            }
        });


**Main Activity XML layout File:** 

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Menu"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Create Account" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewlogs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="View Logs" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is here -

you are getting id of `view_logs_button` but applying click on `create_account_button`(you apply clicl listener on `create_account_button` 2 times so its taking latest click listener) and redirecting to `ViewLogActivity`.

```
Button view_logs_button = findViewById(R.id.viewlogs);
create_account_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // call the view log activity
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick for view log called");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewLogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

To fix the issue apply click listener on `view_logs_button` like below -

```
Button view_logs_button = findViewById(R.id.viewlogs);
view_logs_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // call the view log activity
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick for view log called");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewLogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Hope this will help you!!